# Please migrate this question to StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, status-declined, migration

I have posted [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/32028/22343) on webapps.SE. I was attracted to ask question here because of the site's name (which says *Web **Applications***). Now I think it should go to StackOverflow.

StackOverflow has a special section for Facebook questions [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/). I think it will get better and faster *(which I need to deactivate my account)* answer there. Please migrate it.

Answer (score 7):

The site http://facebook.stackoverflow.com is just a view Stack Overflow that looks purely at questions to do with **developing** Facebook applications. The questions there still need to be about **coding** issues.

What you have here is a problem to do with the management of your Facebook account. These type of questions are **on topic** and perfectly fine here on Web Applications, therefore your question is in the right place.

If we migrated it to Stack Overflow it would probably be closed as **off topic** very quickly.

Comment: So, when will I get the answer? I have to deactivate my account. I will be deleting both, my application and question in next 12hours.

Comment: @SantoshKumar You can't demand answers from the users of these sites. If you need this urgently why don't you contact Facebook directly.

Comment: @SantoshKumar No one can answer the question because you deleted it

Comment: @SantoshKumar If you delete it, then there was no benefit to us or the community for our time, space and hosting. If you want to close your account, why don't you try offering a bounty? It'll get your question more attention and the rep was to be lost anyway.